# What are the rules for expected values to the dotnet ef commands?

Tags: entity-framework-core, dotnet-cli

In an ASP.NET Core application with migrations, running update database gives the following output. It works, and the verbose output displays the default values for a variety of options.

```
dotnet ef --verbose database update 

Setting the data directory to 'C:\temp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\'.
Invoking dependency command 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design' in project '2016-101DP-TreeGame-Auth'
Running C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec 
  --runtimeconfig C:\temp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\temp.runtimeconfig.json
  --depsfile C:\temp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\temp.deps.json 
  --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design\1.0.0-preview2-final\lib\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.dll 
  --assembly C:\temp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\temp.dll 
  --startup-assembly C:\temp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\temp.dll 
  --dispatcher-version 1.0.0-preview2-21431 
  --data-dir C:\temp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\ 
  --project-dir C:\temp 
  --content-root-path C:\temp
  --root-namespace temp
  --verbose update database
Process ID: 12544
Finding DbContext classes...
Using context 'ApplicationDbContext'.
Done.
```

When I try to run the same command with options, the CLI complains that my options have "unexpected values." Here are two examples.

```
dotnet ef --data-dir C:\temp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\ --verbose database update

dotnet ef --data-dir "C:\temp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\" --verbose database update
```

Both tell me this:

> Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandParsingException: Unexpected value 'C:\temp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\' for option 'data-dir'
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)

What are the rules for expected values to the `dotnet ef` commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two layers. `dotnet-ef` reads metadata from the project (and builds it) then calls `ef` using that metadata (including the output assembly paths). You cannot specify the following options from `dotnet ef` since they are determined for you.

- `--assembly`
- `--startup-assembly`
- `--data-dir`
- `--project-dir`
- `--content-root-path`
- `--root-namespace`

The rest of the options that show up in `dotnet ef --help` can be specified on `dotnet ef`.

This should get better as part of issue [#6592](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6592).

Here is some [documentation about dotnet ef](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html).